# Wagtail: How to add button "add subpage" to the action list of a custom listing view (IndexView)?

Tags: python, wagtail

I am constructing the admin menu on a per user basis w/o the explorer view and custom `ModelAdmin` instances.

```
@hooks.register('construct_main_menu')
def hide_page_explorer_menu_item(request, menu_items):
    if request.user.username == 'user1':
        menu_items[:] = [item for item in menu_items if item.name not in [
            'explorer',
            ]
        ]

class CustomAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = MyPage
    menu_label = 'custom ModelAdmin'

    list_display = ('title', "live")
    list_filter = ("date")
    search_fields = ("title")

modeladmin_register(CustomAdmin)
```

But the action list (i.e. the context menus) for the resulting listing view is missing some of the functionallity the explorer view provides.

I specifically need "ADD CHILDPAGE". I know of the hook [`register_page_listing_buttons`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5/reference/hooks.html#register-page-listing-buttons). But you can only register buttons for the explorer view action list.

Is it possible to add the button "add subpage" to the action list of a custom listing view?

---

Explorer listing view:

[image: Explorer View:]

Custom ModelAdmin listing view:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer**

`ModelAdmin` does not use the same system to build up what buttons are listed in their views.

Instead it has a concept of 'helper classes', these are used to generate the URLs and Permission checks which in turn are used to generate the Buttons that appear in the various views.

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/primer.html?highlight=primer

You will need to set up a custom button_helper_class on the `ModelAdmin` instance that will generate the custom buttons that you want in your `IndexView`. To do this you will need to import and extend the `PageButtonHelper` class with a custom `get_buttons_for_obj` method that will return a List of buttons.

**Code Example**

```
# wagtail_hooks.py

from django.urls import reverse
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import (ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register)
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.helpers import (PageAdminURLHelper, PageButtonHelper)
# MyPage model import not included but will be needed

class CustomPageAdminURLHelper(PageAdminURLHelper):

    def get_action_url(self, action, *args, **kwargs):
        if action == 'add-child':
            # note: add_subpage is used as the internal name for adding child pages
            url_name = 'wagtailadmin_pages:add_subpage'
            target_url = reverse(url_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
            return target_url

        # for every other case - just call the parent method
        return super().get_action_url(action, *args, **kwargs)


class CustomPageButtonHelperClass(PageButtonHelper):

    add_child_button_classnames = ['add-child'] # can be anything - just setting this to match convention

    # add a new button generator that mimics the 'copy_button' from existing code
    def add_child_button(self, pk, classnames_add=[], classnames_exclude=[]):
        classnames = self.add_child_button_classnames + classnames_add
        final_classnames = self.finalise_classname(classnames, classnames_exclude)

        return {
            # if we wanted - we can skip the creation of CustomPageAdminURLHelper & generate the URL here
            # but this may work against reusability later
            'url': self.url_helper.get_action_url('add-child', pk), # may need to wrap pk in quote if it could contain non-url-safe chars
            'label': 'Add Child',
            'classname': final_classnames,
            'title': 'Add Child uner this %s' % self.verbose_name
        }

    # override the PageButtonHelper method to 'add' custom buttons
    def get_buttons_for_obj(self, obj, exclude=[], classnames_add=[], classnames_exclude=[]):
        # call the parent class method to get the default set of buttons
        buttons = super().get_buttons_for_obj(obj, exclude, classnames_add, classnames_exclude)

        # set up some variables to do user checks and also get the primary key (id)
        permission_helper = self.permission_helper
        user = self.request.user
        pk = getattr(obj, self.opts.pk.attname)

        # many existing permission helpers are already available - see wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/helpers/permission.py
        if ('add-child' not in exclude and permission_helper.user_can_create(user)):
            # above we follow the convention set up where buttons can be included/excluded easier
            # we also do a permissions check
            # finally we build the button and add it to the end of the buttons list
            add_child_button = self.add_child_button(pk, classnames_add, classnames_exclude)
            buttons.append(add_child_button)

        return buttons

class CustomAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = MyPage
    menu_label = 'custom ModelAdmin'
    button_helper_class = CustomPageButtonHelperClass # added to enable custom button generation
    url_helper_class = CustomPageAdminURLHelper # added to enable custom url generation

    list_display = ('title', "live")
    list_filter = ("date")
    search_fields = ("title")

modeladmin_register(CustomAdmin)
```

**Code Explanation**

- https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/tree/master/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/helpers - contains the code for all helpers, this is important to look at to understand the imports and existing methods being overridden.

`CustomPageButtonHelperClass`

- Override `get_buttons_for_obj` by appending an add_child_button.
- Use the existing permission helper class to do some checks, this will avoid the need to rewrite user & auth logic which can be prone to errors
- Call the method (which we will add) to generate the button content, `add_child_button`
- Add method `add_child_button` - must return an object with url, label, classname and title. Try to keep existing conventions in place where classnames can be appended/removed globally
- The hardest one is the url generation, we will leverage the existing structure of URL helpers but you could just generate this URL in-line.

`CustomPageAdminURLHelper`

- Override the method `get_action_url` and handle the specific case we care about where the 'action' is `'add-child'`
- This method must simply return a string (which will be a relative url), best to use existing system of Django URL reversing.
- The url name for adding a child page is `'wagtailadmin_pages:add_subpage'`
- Finally call the Django reverse util with the passed in args/kwargs and you will get a beautiful url in return.

`CustomAdmin`

- The final step is to set these custom url & button helper classes on your CustomAdmin instance.
- This just needs the `button_helper_class` and `url_helper_class` set to their respective helper overrides.

**Extra Notes & Caveats**

- Have a good read of the ModelAdmin docs, they are very well laid out and help a lot. https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html?highlight=modeladmin%20helpers#
- There are some aspects missing, but the helpers folder in the codebase is quite easy to read and should help you work out the flow of the code you are customising.
- This is assuming you only want to use these custom helpers on Page models, there are subtle differences between how ModelAdmin treats pages and other objects, you can put extra checks in but that is up to you.
- You could shortcut a bit of boilerplate code if you don't care about classnames and following existing modeladmin conventions, that is up to you.
- This assumes your primary keys are URL safe, you will see in the modeladmin code there are lots of extra usage of utils to make everything url safe.
- After the child page is created, the user will go back to the NON-model admin listing of the parent page. Changing this may require a fair bit of extra work but the code above should get you what you want.

Comment: I am so sorry for accepting this answer so late. I was sure I did already.